# Browsers are generating a strange border

Tags: html, border

I went to go and test my site today in Chrome and I noticed that the browser is creating a strange border around certain sections of my site. It's a white border and it encompasses the right and bottom of the window, as well as the right of my sidebar menu. I do not remember this border being there when I was testing the site yesterday. Thinking it was a browser error, I opened the site in Safari and the same problem occurred. I have a feeling this is user error (and probably a very stupid error) but I have no idea how to get rid of it. I cannot test the site properly until this border is gone

I did not write this border into my code and it appears to be some kind of setting that is turned on in the browsers, but I have no idea how to turn it off. I am including an image of the "mystery border" below.

Image is here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tu4U3.png

`Code is here`
http://jsfiddle.net/Feu8H/

Comment: I don't see any css code. Is this normal?

Comment: My bad. Just added the stylesheet to the jsfiddle.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't recreate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Feu8H/1/

Comment: can you share the site url because i am not seeing any border when i opened jsfiddle link in chrome. debugging the actual page with firebug may help

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your css:

```
body{margin: 0;
     padding: 0;}

#nav_container{margin: 0;
     padding: 0;}
```

If that doesn't work, try adding this class:

```
.cBoth{clear: both;}
```

and after the #nav_container div write in this div:

hopefully should get rid of the borders.

Answer (score 0):

Those borders come from the scroll. Replace `overflow:scroll;` with `overflow:hidden;` in html, body tag will remove those borders, but the scroll too. For sidebar look in #nav_bar and do the same replacement. http://jsfiddle.net/Feu8H/3/

POST EDIT: A better solution would be to use `overflow:auto;` instead `overflow:hidden;` because with `overflow:hidden` is possible that some visitors will not see all the content.

Comment: I know, it also had to do with a setting I had enabled in System Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was the problem. It had nothing to do with any of my code. In fact, it had to do with my computer settings (OSX Mountain Lion). I generally use a trackpad when I build sites, but today I happened to have my USB mouse connected. There is a setting in System Preferences>Personal>General that changes how scrollbars are shown depending on the mouse peripheral you have connected. Connecting a USB mouse caused the scrollbars to always be shown, regardless of if you were scrolling or not. These "mystery borders" were scrollbars. I just changed the setting and now everything works fine.